# Set creation Time of a directory in Java

Tags: java, linux, file, java-8

I want to change the creation time of a directory in java (Linux).
Files are no problem:

```
Files.createFile(file.toPath());
        Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "basic:lastModifiedTime", FileTime.fromMillis(creationDate), NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "basic:creationTime", FileTime.fromMillis(creationDate), NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

That works.

But if I try to set this by directory creation nothing happens:

```
Files.createDirectory(file.toPath());
        Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "basic:lastModifiedTime", FileTime.fromMillis(creationDate), NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "basic:creationTime", FileTime.fromMillis(creationDate), NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

What could be the problem or is another approach the better way? (I use JDK 8)

Comment: If I remember correctly *NIX does not store creation time on folder inodes. Only modification time.

Comment: Have you tried to read the creation time of an existing folder on your file system? Does it return anything valid?

Comment: Which file system are you using? `mount |grep ' / '`

Comment: The answer from @fredrik is right and helps me.

Comment: @fredrik Im unclear I thought creationTIme was not stored at all for linux, or is it only not stored for folders ?